OSError:[Errno 30]Read-only file system:'2024-04-05-06-15-30.176066' File"/var/task/lambda_function.py",in lambda_handler model_load=StarDist2D(conf)
while running aws lambda function and doing inference with DL model over container running in lambda, when i am downloading my model from s3 it is running but when i instantiate a StarDist2D(conf) object it is giving this error. Not sure whether it is due to Stardist or something instance object or something else since there is timestamp infront of error as you can see in question heading.
Code for lambda_handler
        def download_model_from_s3(bucket_name, model_key, local_model_path):
    try:
        s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, model_key, local_model_path)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error downloading model file from S3: {e}")
        return False

local_model_path = '/tmp/' + model_file_name
def download_model_from_s3(bucket_name, model_key, local_model_path):
    try:
        s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, model_key, local_model_path)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error downloading model file from S3: {e}")
        return False
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Check if the event is an S3 event
    print("this is event",event)
    if 'Records' in event and len(event['Records']) > 0 and 's3' in event['Records'][0]:
        bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
        print("this is key",key)
        image_name = key.split("/")[-1]
        print("this is image_name",image_name)
        
        # Check if the uploaded object is in the validationimages folder
        if key.startswith('ValidationImages/'):
            # Process the uploaded image here
            print("line no 67")
            np.random.seed(42)
            image_path = '/tmp/'+image_name
            s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, key, image_path)
            
            def imreadReshape(key):
                if ".tif" in image_name:
                    imageRead = imread(image_path)
                    if np.ndim(imageRead) == 2:
                        return imageRead
                    imageRead = np.array(imageRead)
                    imageRead = cv2.resize(imageRead,(768,768))
                    return imageRead[:,:,0]
                else:
                    print("line no 80")
                    imageRead = cv2.imread(image_path)
                    print("line no 82")
                    if np.ndim(imageRead) == 2:
                        return imageRead
                    imageRead = cv2.resize(imageRead,(768,768))
                    return imageRead[:,:,0]
            X_val = [image_name]
            X_val = list(map(imreadReshape,X_val))
            n_channel = 1 if X_val[0].ndim == 2 else X_val[0].shape[-1]  #If no third dim. then number of channels = 1. Otherwise get the num channels from the last dim.
            axis_norm = (0,1)  
            if n_channel > 1:
                print("Normalizing image channels %s." % ('jointly' if axis_norm is None or 2 in axis_norm else 'independently'))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            
            X_val = [x/255 for x in X_val]
            rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
            
            print(Config2D.__doc__)
            gputools_available()
            
            n_rays = 32 #ok
            use_gpu = True and gputools_available() #ok
            
            grid = (2,2) # ok
            
            conf = Config2D (
                n_rays       = n_rays,
                grid         = grid,
                use_gpu      = use_gpu,
                n_channel_in = n_channel,
                train_patch_size = (768,768)
            )
            
            if download_model_from_s3(bucket_name, model_key, local_model_path):
            ## Load the model
                new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(local_model_path)
            print("Load Model Complete")
            model_load = StarDist2D(conf)


Could you post the full stack trace for the error in your question?

Take the error at face value -- if it says read-only filesystem, it means you're trying to write to a read-only filesystem. Maybe you need to qualify a path to be interacting with /tmp instead of the current working directory (on high-security systems / is often deliberately read-only), or maybe your host encountered filesystem corruption and remounted read-only automatically.

I solved it. Actually we need to change the default directory of lambda environment at the beginning of the code to /tmp/ so that everything is written to tmp. So just by adding one statement would do the trick.
   os.chdir("/tmp/")

